# No route registered for WebJob

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have setup an Azure WebJob which is linked to a website (which is working fine)

I seem to get lots of these errors:

```
Http Action - Response from host 'site.scm.azurewebsites.net': 'NotFound' Response Headers: Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Date: Sat, 06 Dec 2014 05:00:06 GMT
Set-Cookie:     ARRAffinity=cookie;Path=/;Domain=site.scm.azurewebsites.net
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
 Body: "No route registered for '/api/triggeredwebjobs/WebJobName/run'"
```

I am not sure precisely when these errors started - The Azure management portal doesn't seem to offer an easy way to skip to the end of the list.

The WebJob was working up until a few days ago, then stopped. I haven't changed anything of consequence I believe.

Googleing this error doesn't seem to throw up any meaning to it.

If any extra required information is required, please ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this error, I deleted the job and then re-published it. Now this error has disappeared.

Comment: I have this error even if i rebuild, create a new zip, and re-add the job