# Azure Usage And Billing Portal DataGenStatus always pending

Tags: azure, dashboard, azureportal, azure-billing-api

I have completed all the process describes in the tutorial Azure Usage and Billing Insights (AUBI) Portal https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureUsageAndBillingPortal  without problems but at the end in the dashboard website the data generation status is always **Pending** because of this there are tables of power bi that are empty like AzureUsageRecords, ReportRequests and Reports. Does anyone know why this problem is caused? Thank you very much and I hope your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the WebJobUsageDaily Project -> Program.cs, there is this :

```
Commons.Utils.UpdateSubscriptionStatus(s.Id, DataGenStatus.Pending, DateTime.UtcNow);
```

This line updates the pending status in the database. And in the WebJobBillingData Project -> Functions.cs inside  ProcessQueueMessage(BillingRequest br) function, the last line is:

```
Commons.Utils.UpdateSubscriptionStatus(br.SubscriptionId, DataGenStatus.Completed, DateTime.UtcNow);
```

This line updates the completed status.

I suggest, first checking if both the WebJob has run successfully and if yes please check if something is failing between these two lines.

P.S: Mine was always showing Pending because ida:ClientId and ida:Password in App.config was incorrect.

Comment: I have checked the lines and between them but I dont see the fail also ida:Clientld and ida:Password i think is correct.

Comment: Something is failing because the second line is not getting executed. Can you debug the code in your local machine and check. Especially check all the rest api calls to the Azure Billing API

Comment: I finally found the problem in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27332324/no-route-registered-for-webjob only deleted the job and then re-published it.